# Displaying ChartJS tooltip on mouseover of bar/line

Tags: chart.js

I have the following code which shows a chart containing a line and some bars.  When I hover over the line points, I see the tooltip for that line point, which is perfect.  When I hover over any bar, I see a tooltip for EVERY bar as well as the line, which is bad.  How do I show a tooltip that only shows the particular bar (and intersecting line if it exists) I am hovering over?

FWIW I've tried a couple variations of the tooltips/hover options based on the chartjs docs but I couldn't get any particular combination to work.

https://codepen.io/uglyhobbitfeet/pen/PooLgev?editors=1010

```
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'point',
  },
  hover: {
    mode: 'point',
  },
```

Docs are here:

- https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html
- https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your implementation, remove that piece of code.

```
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'point',
  },
  hover: {
    mode: 'point',
  },
```

and then add the mode in the `tooltips` a few lines down:

```
tooltips: {
  mode: 'point',
  callbacks: {}
}
```

Since the points down sit in the range of the bar chart, they aren't technically intersecting.

But if you do create a point within the range, it'll be able to pick it up on the tooltip.